# Splitting columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': 1, 'coords':{0: [(-43.21,-22.15),(-43.22,-22.22)]}})
```

How can I separate the values from the coords column so that the first item in each list forms the column called latitude and the second the column called longitude, as below?

```
id|  latitude     |longitude
1 |(-43.21,-43.22)|(-22.15, -22.22)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `join` with column explode

```
df1=df1.join(pd.DataFrame(df1.coords.tolist(),index=df1.index,columns=['latitude','longitude']))

Out[138]: 
   id                                coords          latitude         longitude
0   1  [(-43.21, -22.15), (-43.22, -22.22)]  (-43.21, -22.15)  (-43.22, -22.22)
```

Comment: This will be faster than apply

Answer (score 0):

`apply` is a straightforward way:

```
df1['latitude'] = df1.coords.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df1['longitude'] = df1.coords.apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

Output:

```
   id                                coords          latitude         longitude
0   1  [(-43.21, -22.15), (-43.22, -22.22)]  (-43.21, -22.15)  (-43.22, -22.22)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using the `.str` accessor

```
df1['latitude'] = df1['coords'].str[0]
df1['longitude'] = df1['coords'].str[1]
```

Time difference:

```
df1['latitude'] = df1['coords'].str[0] 
# 539 µs ± 15.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
df1['latitude'] = df1.coords.apply(lambda x: x[0]) 
# 624 µs ± 16.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

take the tuple for lat:

```
lat = [(x[0][0],x[1][0]) for x in df1['coords'].values]
df1['latitude'] = lat
```

same as for longt:

```
longt = [(x[0][1],x[1][1]) for x in df1['coords'].values]
df1['longtitude'] = longt
```

drop coords columns:

```
df1.drop(columns='coords')
```

hope this helps!